# How to save picture in BLOB format?

Tags: oracle, vb6

I did code for procedure that prompts for a .jpeg file, converts that file to a Byte array, and saves the Byte Array to the table using the Append chunk method.
Another procedure retrieves the picture image from the table using the GetChunk method, converts the data to a file and displays that file in the Picture box.

Now, my question is that how do I save that image displayed in picture box into the database, so that I can perform operations like: add/update etc.
I did something like this way:

```
Private Sub CmdSave_Click()
  if(cmbRNO=" ") then
    sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE(ROLLNO,PICS)"
    sql = sql + "VALUES(" & RNo & ","& picture1.picture &")"
    Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
  Else
    sql = "UPDATE STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE SET "
    sql = sql + "ROLLNO= " & Val(CmbRNO) & ","
    sql = sql + "PICS=" & Picture1.Picture & "  "
    sql = sql + "WHERE ROLLNO= " & Val(CmbRNO) & ""

    Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
  End If
End Sub
<code for appendchunk method>    
Public Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim PictBmp As String
  Dim ByteData() As Byte   'Byte array for Blob data.
  Dim SourceFile As Integer
  ' Open the BlobTable table.
  strSQL = "Select ID, DOC from LOB_TABLE WHERE ID = 1"
  Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  Rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
  Rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
  Rs.Open strSQL, Cn
  ' Retrieve the picture and update the record.
  CommonDialog1.Filter = "(*.jpeg)|*.jpeg"
  CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
  PictBmp = CommonDialog1.FileName
  ' Save Picture image to the table column.
  SourceFile = FreeFile
  Open PictBmp For Binary Access Read As SourceFile
  FileLength = LOF(SourceFile)  ' Get the length of the file.
  If FileLength = 0 Then
      Close SourceFile
      MsgBox PictBmp & " empty or not found."
      Exit Sub
  Else
      Numblocks = FileLength / BlockSize
     LeftOver = FileLength Mod BlockSize
      ReDim ByteData(LeftOver)
      Get SourceFile, , ByteData()
      Rs(1).AppendChunk ByteData()
      ReDim ByteData(BlockSize)
      For i = 1 To Numblocks
          Get SourceFile, , ByteData()
          Rs(1).AppendChunk ByteData()
      Next i
      Rs.Update   'Commit the new data.
     Close SourceFile
  End If
  End Sub
```

While trying to save image to specific record, run-time error occurs: 
inconsistent datatype,expected BLOB got number
Where as:
    ?sql
    UPDATE STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE SET ROLLNO= 132,PICS=688195876  WHERE ROLLNO= 132

Comment: Your first paragraph explains what you need to do. Call `SavePicture()` on it, load that file and append the chunk. Your posted code is failing as the `.Picture` property returns the handle by default, not the data.

Comment: I did code for append chunk and get chunk and I am able to get that image from file but can't save into the oracle table.................

Comment: You need to use the `AppendChunk()` method. If you're having problems with that, try posting that code instead.

Comment: Why not update your question?